# Realloc existing data is getting lost

Tags: c, gnu

I am learning c programming language. The program below takes the output of a command to variable and prints it. But when reallocate the memory to extend the memory I am losing the old data.

Can you please telling what I am missing here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

FILE *fp;

char r[1024];
fp=popen("/bin/ls /etc/","r");

if(fp==NULL){
    perror("Failed to run the command");
    exit(-1);
}

int totallengthread=0,alloc_size=1024;
char *buffer = (char*) malloc(alloc_size*sizeof(char));
memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
int lenofbuff=0;
while(fgets(r,1023,fp)!=NULL){
 concat(buffer,r);
 lenofbuff=strlen(buffer);
 totallengthread+=lenofbuff;
 if(totallengthread>=alloc_size){
     alloc_size+=1024;
     realloc(buffer,alloc_size);
 }

}
pclose(fp);
printf("this is the out put =>%s",buffer);
free(buffer);
 return 0;
}
void concat(char *dest, const char *source){
    char *d=dest;
    char *s=source;
    while (*d != '\0') {
              d++;
           }
     while(*s!='\0')
        {
            *d++=*s++;
        }
    *d='\0';
}
```

Comment: This line: `memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer))` doesn't do what you think it does.  (It's also unnecessary.)

Comment: You should check the buffer size (and reallocate) *before* you `concat(buffer,r);`

Comment: Rather than `fgets` and a subsequent `strlen`, you ought to read the data with `fread` and use the return value.

Comment: Reading a function's documentation definitely helps: `man realloc` or look up the [Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5).

Comment: @WilliamPursell — the trouble with `fread()` instead of `fgets()` is that `fread()` pays no attention to lines unless the input happens to be coming from a terminal or a pipe.  If you ask `fread()` to read 1023 characters from a disk file, it will do so, unless there's an EOF before then.  Using POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
returns the length, including null bytes which are also a problem with `fgets()`; it has subtly different downsides (single lines that are just too big for comfort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bit closer to what you want. Please see the comments in the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void concat(char *dest, const char *source){
    char *d=dest;
    char *s=source;
    while (*d != '\0'){
        d++;
    }
    while(*s!='\0'){
        *d++=*s++;
    }
    *d='\0';
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char r[1024];
    fp=popen("/bin/ls /etc/","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        perror("Failed to run the command");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int totallengthread=0,alloc_size=1024;
    char *buffer = malloc(alloc_size*sizeof*buffer); //This is nicer because is type independent
    memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof*buffer); //I believe this is what you wanted.
    int lenofbuff=0;
    while(fgets(r,sizeof r,fp)){ // as @chux said this avoids hardcoding 1024-1. You also don't need to compare to NULL. 
        concat(buffer,r);
        lenofbuff=strlen(buffer);
        totallengthread+=lenofbuff;
        if(totallengthread>=alloc_size){
            alloc_size+=1024;
            buffer = realloc(buffer,alloc_size); //you need to use the return of realloc
        }
    }
    pclose(fp);
    printf("this is the out put =>%s",buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

As @chux mentioned, as in any memory allocation you should check whether the returned pointers are `NULL`, that would mean the allocation failed.

Also, please note that

```
memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof*buffer);
```

is equivalent to

```
memset(buffer,0,sizeof*buffer);
```

and as @thebusybee mentioned this is only setting the first element of the array to the NULL character, if you were intended to fill the whole array you should do 
    memset(buffer,0,alloc_size*sizeof*buffer);

or just replacing

```
char *buffer = malloc(alloc_size*sizeof*buffer);
memset(buffer,0,alloc_size*sizeof*buffer);
```

for

```
char *buffer = calloc(alloc_size,sizeof*buffer);
```

Comment: The `memset()` is still wrong, because `sizeof*buffer` is equal to `sizeof buffer[0]` which is equal to `sizeof (char)` which is 1. It has to be `memset(buffer, '\0', allocsize * sizeof buffer[0])`. The combination of `malloc()` and `memset(..., 0, ...)` can be replaced by `calloc()`, BTW.

Comment: @thebusybee I agree that is the right way to set the whole allocated memory to 0, but that's assuming that the OP wanted to set the whole memory and not the first char to `'\0'`

Comment: Good point. I was misled by the call of `memset()` which I never consider to use for setting just an element. I would use `buffer[0] = '\0';` of course.

Comment: `while(fgets(r,1023,fp)!=NULL){` is off-by-one in an OK way.  Suggest ``while(fgets(r, sizeof r ,fp)!=NULL){`` or simply ``while (fgets(r,sizeof r ,fp)) {``

Comment: @chux True, that hardcoded 1023 is not very nice. I just tried to fix the issues most closely related to the OP's one, but indeed I can add that.

Answer (score 4):

`realloc()` is a building block  for a general purpose memory reallocation.

Code needs to use the return value from `realloc()` as that is the pointer, on success, to the reallocated data.

```
void * tptr = realloc(buffer, alloc_size);
// Detect out-of-memory 
if (tptr == NULL && alloc_size > 0) {
  // Handle it in some way
  fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failure\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

buffer = tptr;
```

---

Note: Various other non-allocation code issues exist.